# Fitnesse test page throwing an exception

Tags: java, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, fitness

I'm running Fitnesse testing tool via Jenkins. Jenkins runs fitnesse after fixed interval. Following is the test page:-[Fitnesse Test Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBZ55.png)

1.creating script file
2. running it

In this, I'm simply printing message but this test page sometimes thrown an exception:-

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:270)
    at com.objectmentor.fixtures.LineGatherer.readLine(LineGatherer.java:42)
    at com.objectmentor.fixtures.CommandLineFixture.flush(CommandLineFixture.java:291)
    at com.objectmentor.fixtures.CommandLineFixture.flushProcess(CommandLineFixture.java:65)
    at com.objectmentor.fixtures.CommandLineFixture.endTable(CommandLineFixture.java:59)
    at com.objectmentor.fixtures.CommandLineFixture.doTable(CommandLineFixture.java:48)
    at fit.Fixture.interpretFollowingTables(Fixture.java:121)
    at fit.Fixture.interpretTables(Fixture.java:107)
    at fit.Fixture.doTables(Fixture.java:81)
    at fit.FitServer.process(FitServer.java:81)
    at fit.FitServer.run(FitServer.java:56)
    at fit.FitServer.main(FitServer.java:41)
```

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvhQB.png)

This exception thrown sometimes and sometimes it work perfectly. It fail 2 out of 10 times . and I didn't change anything , i am simply running same test after every 30 min.

Comment: It looks like the error comes from inside the fixture code of `com.objectmentor.fixtures.CommandLineFixture`. 
Are the failures always on the same machine (i.e. does your Jenkins installation have multiple executors to run jobs, and can you link the failed jobs to one, or some, of them?
Is there maybe a timing issue? That the fixture might decide it takes too long for the desired value to show up. `sleep` is not an exact command as far as I know so the exact timing between messages may vary.

Comment: Yeah, failures run on the same machine. And not only this test page fail, There are more test pages performing similar operation and they randomly fail there is no connection which test will fail. I tried to find the root cause but didn't get any reason for these random failure.